# Seeking Expert Advice on Terraform Deployment Cleanup

Tags: ansible, automation, terraform, amazon-cloudformation, devops

I've been successfully using Terraform for various deployments, managing to create multiple environments for different clients using a single Jenkins job. However, I've hit a roadblock when it comes to cleanup or then i run Terraform Destroy.

let's say I deploy environments for clients 1, 2, and 3 with the same job. when when i destroy it only destroys any one of the clients to which I provide the parameter after that I can not clean the remaining two clients, when I write terraform destroy it gives me this notification.

```
No changes. No objects need to be destroyed.

Either you have not created any objects yet or the existing objects were already deleted outside of Terraform.

Destroy complete! Resources: 0 destroyed.
```

It seems like managing separate state files for each deployment might be the solution, but I'm unsure about the best practices. maybe there is a solution inside Terraform for this which I am not aware of.

Could you share your insights or recommend best practices for efficiently managing Terraform state files in scenarios like mine? Your expertise would be highly valuable.

Thanks in advance,
Yousuf

Comment: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state/workspaces

Comment: Sorry, i was not aware of the concept of Zabbix Workspace. Now I understand how I can manage multiple deployments with the same script. Thanks,
Yousuf